# Multi string search with ransack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ransack

I want to do search with multiple string like below using `ransack`

`SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE email LIKE 'kin%' OR name LIKE 'jeno%' ORDER BY 1;`

so i have tried with `ransack`

1) `User.search(:email_cont => ["kingston@jenorish.com","admin@jenorish.com"]).result`

2) `User.search(:email_cont => "kingston@jenorish.com","admin@jenorish.com").result`

But i failed to get the result,so please giude me

Currently am using like

```
User.where("email like ? or email like ?", "%abc", "%ddd")
```

How to do with `ransack`?

Answer (score 0):

I think `ransack` can't solve this.

```
# search.rb on ransack gem
def build(params)
  collapse_multiparameter_attributes!(params).each do |key, value|
    if Constants::S_SORTS.include?(key)
      send("#{key}=", value)
    elsif base.attribute_method?(key)
      base.send("#{key}=", value)
    elsif @context.ransackable_scope?(key, @context.object)
      add_scope(key, value)
    elsif !Ransack.options[:ignore_unknown_conditions]
      raise ArgumentError, "Invalid search term #{key}"
    end
  end
  self
end
```

`params` argment is like `{ :email_cont => ["kingston@jenorish.com","admin@jenorish.com"] }`

In `build` method,just call `send("email_cont=", ["kingston@jenorish.com","admin@jenorish.com"])`

So you just do as below:

```
User.where("email like ? or email like ?", "%abc", "%ddd")
# SQL is ...
# =>  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE (email like '%abc' or email like '%ddd')
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @shoji,Currently am using this way only i want to use `ransack` instead of my code.